# Unity touch and ui button

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Just like the image above, we have a model and a canvas in front of it. It have collider at foots, and i need onclick event in the button also. What i want is the gameobject no action when user click button, but now it's hard to click the button.

Here is my code below:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        EventSystem es = EventSystem.current;
        Debug.Log("IsPointerOverGameObject === " + es.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId));
        Debug.Log("currentSelectedGameObject === " + es.currentSelectedGameObject);
        if (!(es.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId) && es.currentSelectedGameObject != null))
        {
            Debug.Log("Handle touch === ");
            HandleTouchEvent();
        }
    }
```

Does someone has any ideas?

Comment: Are they just buttons?

Comment: @TimCooley Yeah, buttons in ScrollRect

Answer (score 2):

I think when you touch the `gameobject` both of your UI and other gameobjects get affected so you should exclude the times that the user uses UI elements like this,

```
 public class TouchExample : MonoBehaviour {
  void Update () 
    {
    // Check if there is a touch
     if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
      {
       // Check if finger is over a UI element 
        if(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
       {
    Debug.Log("UI is touched");
    //so when the user touched the UI(buttons) call your UI methods 
       }
    else
       {
    Debug.Log("UI is not touched");
   //so here call the methods you call when your other in-game objects are touched 
       }
      } 
     }
    }
```